# How to check if the git branch is newly created or not?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-bash

Is there is a way to check if the git branch is newly created

For example

- git checkout master
- git checkout -b feature

I have a requirement that I need to identify that a given branch is brand new where there is no new commits on it, just like feature branch created above.

for example: let take bug_fix branch which is created out of master and committed some code into it. Suppose I am not aware of that commits, I should be able to fire some commands and after it, I should be able to know that it has some commits that were made after it was created out of master branch.

Ultimately I need to verify it in .gitlab-ci.yml file, is there predefined variable to check it ?

Any other alternative is also welcome. Thanks in advance for dropping by.

Comment: Is your definition of "brand new" that "it must not have commits on it only available through this branch"?

Comment: I ask because if I create a branch today, on master, and leave it there for one year, never committing anything to that branch. Is that branch still "brand new"?

Comment: Have you tried to look up in the browser ? Or you are searching for some command line (bash style)? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen At the moment when I check it should not contain any new commits, later it can have commits as a usual branch.

Comment: @Danizavtz yes i did, normally i couldn't find as of now

Comment: What I meant was to ask if the "brand new" definition had anything to do with the age of the branch, or whether it was purely based on the fact that it contained commits or not.

Comment: To see if a branch has commits on it that aren't in master you can execute `git log master..branchname`. But if you first create a new branch, check it out, apply 2 commits on it, and then create yet another branch now, the git log command I just showed will tell you that both branches contains commits not on master. It depends on whether you consider the latest branch there "brand new" based on the relationship with master or based on the relationship with any branch. Please think hard and carefully on your exact definition of "brand new".

Answer (score 1):

In the example you give, the `merge-base` of `master` and `feature` is identical to `feature`. So that gives you a template for identifying these situations.

Comment: yes you are correct, but how can i verify merge-base though commands. is it possible to check in existing branch as in gitlab i will not be able to checkout on other branch and do some git commands

Comment: I didn't understand any of those words, sorry.

Comment: @AnandKumar can you rephrase the second sentence in your comment? Are you trying to lock something down based on commits existing on a feature branch?

Comment: when the pipeline trigger (via gitlab-ci) it only works on existing branch.. so being on the same branch (git checkout is not an option) can we figure out whether there is any new commits after the branch was created? Also as it is going to be implemented in the gitlab-ci.yml file, verifying commit by looking the logs for parent branch and the feature branch is not an option to me... sorry for my english.. I hope i am able to explain you what i am trying to say.. but thanks for showing interest.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab specific:

```
# First commit of the branch.
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
when: on_success
```

If this is the creation of a new branch the $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA variable will be what you see above.